# Translating Teapot lid

Tags: characters

This lid is from a 'Japanese' cast iron teapot lid. I was told the Japanese used Chinese Characters on cast iron teapots. Can anyone verify this? Could I also please get a translation.[image: lid with Chinese characters]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Japanese term 勤續 means "duty"

結婚勤續二十周年紀念 literally means "20th Anniversary of marry duty

It is better to translate it as  "20th Anniversary of Diligent Marriage"

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much,, would it be like a anniversary present?

Comment: Sounds like it, yes. Japanese still use a lot of kanji for formal occasions. A lot of Japanese martial arts achievement certificates are still written in kanji, IIRC, like karate advancement, and so on.